# File object empty when sending to server ng-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, jquery-file-upload, ng-file-upload

Im using ng-file-upload to upload a basic single file to my server.

I can select the file, see the file name i have selected, and pass the file object (`$scope.myFiles[0]`) to my angular service. However, when populating my HTTP data property with the file, inspecting the HTTP request in dev tools, file is empty object.

Controller:

```
UploadService.upload( { data: { file: $scope.myFiles[0], 'category': $scope.selectedCategory}})
    .success(function (data) {
    ////
    ////
```

UploadService:

```
app.factory('UploadService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        upload: function (something) {
            console.log(something);

            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/upload',
                data: something
            });
        }
    }
});
```

With the above, inspecting in dev tools HTTP requests, i see:

```
Request Payload:
    {data: {file: {}, category: "Friend Card"}}
     data:
         {file: {}, category: "Friend Card"}
         category:"Friend Card"
         file:{}
```

Looking at the output of console.log(something), i can see the file via:

```
{
    $hashKey:"object:107"
    lastModified:1465716430000
    lastModifiedDate:Sun Jun 12 2016 08:27:10 GMT+0100 (BST)
    name:"Postcard.JPG"
    size:522622
    type:"image/jpeg"
    webkitRelativePath:""
}
```

---

Have changed function to have a header type via:

```
return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/upload',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': something.data.file.type
            },
            data: {
                "file": something.data.file,
                "category": something.data.category
            }
        });
```

I can see in dev tools:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:48
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Cookie:_ga=GA1.1.2023678669.1463291637; _gat=1
Host:localhost:8585
Origin:http://localhost:8585
Referer:http://localhost:8585/pages/
```

Specifically: Content-Type:image/jpeg so it looks correct, however file is still and empty object.

Comment: Use `Upload.upload({url: ..., file: file})` to upload the file to the server instead of $http

Comment: @danial - thanks, but i dont understand.. Instead of http?? Do you have an example?

Comment: There are plenty of examples on the docs: Upload.upload({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/upload',
                data: something
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer came partly from danial above...

The ng-file-upload lib comes with a number of API's and methods that can be injected in to your angular app, one of which is 'Upload' service.

I injected this in to my controller, and followed the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/1118/

```
Upload.upload({
  url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
  data: {username: $scope.username, file: file},
});
```